# Ruby Regex to capture value only of the last matching group

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got confused about using non-greedy regex in Ruby when the matching should be done from the end of the string.

Assuming that my string:

```
s = "Some words (some nonsense) and more words (target group)"
```

And I want to get "(target group)" in result. How can I do that? Was trying the following:

greedy:

```
s.match(/\(.*\)$/)[0]
=> "(some nonsense) and more words (target group)"

s.match(/\(.*\)/)[0]
=> "(some nonsense) and more words (target group)"
```

non-greedy:

```
s.match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]
=> "(some nonsense)"

s.match(/\(.*?\)$/)[0]
=> "(some nonsense) and more words (target group)"
```

Please note, that initial string may or may not include any number of groups in "()".

Comment: Keep in mind that a pattern is used by the regex engine from the left to the right, thus, using greedy or lazy quantifiers doesn't change anything. pobrelkey gave you a way to avoid the problem using a negated character class.

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte, I realize that's what I was struggling with. No way to enforce regex engine to work in opposite direction, I guess?\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question.  So my apologies if I get this wrong:

Are you sure you need `.*?` when `[^)]*` will do?

```
s.match(/\([^)]*\)$/)[0]
=> "(target group)"
```

If you insist on using `.*?` anyway, precede your reluctant match with a greedy match:

```
s.match(/^.*(\(.*?\))$/)[1]
=> "(target group)"
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks to be working as I wanted. I don't insist on using non-greedy mode at all, that was just my first thought. So do I get your solution right - search for any chars surrounded by ( and ) in the end of the string, that does not include ')'

Comment: Correct - `[^)]` matches any character other than a right parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

non-greedy regex approach using `scan`

```
s.scan(/\(.*?\)/).last
=>"(target group)"
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `s.scan(/\(.*?\)/).last`? The OP says (clumsily) that there may be any number of parentheses before the final pair that we want to match.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've edited it to reflect what is being asked for

Comment: It looks to be working fine as well, but would be hard to use if I decide to utilize this match for replacement in sub() method, for example.

Answer (score 1):

And here is a non-regexp version:

```
s = "Some words (some nonsense) and more words (target group)"

p s[(s.rindex('(')+1)...s.rindex(')')] #=> target group
```

Answer (score 0):

negative-set with negative-look-ahead

```
s.match(/\([^)]*\)(?!.*\(.*\))/)[0]
```

.. negative-look-ahead can be at the end of captured expression

non-greedy (lazy) with negative-look-ahead

```
s.match(/\((?!.*\(.*\)).*?\)/)[0]
```

.. negative-look-ahead must be before the first repetetion (here lazy = non-greedy)